# How to get the inner HTML code using request in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am trying to scrape a webpage for current train timings. I am using 'request' to get the html. However, the webpage that I want to scrape uses javascript to fill a table containing the timings. This means that the timings that I want to get are in innerHTML and as far as I know (which is not that far ;P), request returns the outerHTML.

So my question is how do I get the innerHTML code using request? If request cannot fulfil the requirements, what should I use?

Code:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');


request('<The Webpage URL>',(error,response,html) => 
{
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200)
    {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const stationName = $('#headerText').text().trim();
        const Departures = $('.departure departure_noics departure_odd');
        console.log($.text());
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scrape dynamic pages you need a headless browser like [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/).

Another way to get the data would be to check if the site makes XHR requests and loads data. Then you could directly use the accessed JSON.

If the data is already present in the loaded HTML you could also try to extract it by other means (RegEx, search replace).

Comment: PhantomJS is not maintained anymore I would suggest [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) from Google.

Comment: Thank you so much. Since I am very new to this topic, I don't know what terms to search for. Thanks a lot both of you. :)